# ngx-bootstrap dropdown menu DOM is not being rendered on init

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I'm not able to get routerLink activated on the dropdown on init.
It works after I trigger the dropdown by clicking on it once and keeps working even after I close it.

It isn't working on init because the dropdown DOM is not rendered by that point.
It gets rendered after the dropdown button is clicked.

I want the dropdown list rendered and hidden on init please.

**StackBlitz that reproduces the issue:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-dropdown

This is the default stackblitz for ngx-bootstrap-dropdown.

If DOM is observed, on init, the dropdown elements are not rendered but after it is opened and closed, the elements are there.

On init before the button is clicked
[image]

After the dropdown is clicked and closed, the ul is there
[image]

What I am looking for is a proper way to use the dropdown pre-rendered (and definitely hidden) so that routerLink is already working

Comment: Drop down will not render options unless they are clicked. If you inspect the element, you will find no options rendered.

Comment: I understand. But opening the dropdown once and closing it, they are rendered but hidden. I want them to be initially rendered but hidden. I can trigger a show and hide which will render it but that isn't the proper way.

Comment: Its a default feature. Use element Ref to trigger a click on init